# Which Data Structure should I choose?

Tags: data-structures

I am thinking to list the top scores for a game. More than 300000 players are to be listed in order by their top score. Players can update their high score by typing in their name, and their new top score. Only 10 scores show up at a time, and the user can type in which place they want to start with. So if they type "100100" then the whole list should refresh, and show them the 100,100th score through the 100,109th score. So what data structure should I use in this case? I am thinking to use **hashTable** with users' names as keys, it would take constant time to update their scores. But what if a user's previous score is at 100,100th, and after he updated his score his score became the highest one in whole list? Then if by using hash table it would take **linear time** since I need to compare each score in the list to make sure is the highest one. Therefore, is there any better data structure to choose beside using **hashTable**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose the data structure that is optimized for the *most common operation*.  By your description of an ordered list probably the most common operation will be viewing the list (and jumping around in it).

If you use a hashtable with the user's names as keys, then it will be very expensive to display the list ordered by score, and very expensive to compute different views when viewers skip around in the list.

Instead, using a simple list sorted by score will make all of the "view" operations very cheap and very easy to implement.  When a user updates their score, simply do a linear (`O(n)`) search for the user by name and remove their old entry.  Then, since the list is sorted, you can search it in `O(log n)` time to find where to re-insert their new entry in the list.

Comment: Thanks for your good suggestion. So does your `O(logn)` time means if the new score is smaller than the previous score, then search forward. If larger, then search backward. Just like balanced binary search tree  to do a "split-search" which also takes `O(logn)` ?

Comment: When you update the score, you can also use the _old score_ to achieve an `O(log n)` performance for removal. This may find a range, but you can scan for the desired user within that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a map (ordered tree) based container with score keys and a hash with name keys. Let the values be a link to your entities stored in a list or array etc. i.e. store the data as you like an make indeces for the different access you need performed fast.